# SQL Query : should return Single Record if Search Condition met, otherwise return Multiple Records

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-tuning

I have table with Billions of Records, Table structure is like :

```
ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
MY_SEARCH_COLUMN NUMBER,
```

`MY_SEARCH_COLUMN` will have Numeric value upto 15 Digit in length.

What I want is, if any specific record is matched, I will have to get that matched value only,

i.e. : If I enter `WHERE MY_SEARCH_COLUMN = 123454321` and table has value `123454321` then this only should be returned.

But if exact value is not matched, I will have to get next 10 values from the table.

i.e. : if I enter `WHERE MY_SEARCH_COLUMN = 123454321` and column does not have the value `123454321` then it should return 10 values from the table which is greater than `123454321`

**Both the case should be covered in single SQL Query**, and I have have to keep in mind the **Performance** of the Query. I have already created Index on the `MY_SEARCH_COLUMN` columns, so other suggestions are welcome to improve the Performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be tricky to do without using a proc or maybe some dynamic SQL, but we can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, MY_SEARCH_COLUMN,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MY_SEARCH_COLUMN) rn
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE MY_SEARCH_COLUMN >= 123454321
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable WHERE MY_SEARCH_COLUMN = 123454321)
                THEN 1
                ELSE 10 END;
```

The basic idea of the above query is that we assign a row number to all records matching the target or greater.  Then, we query using either a row number of 1, in case of an exact match, or all row numbers up to 10 in case of no match.

Comment: Thank you @Tim, This the exactly what I want. But still I am facing performance issue, I already have index on the column, is there anything we can do to improve the performance?

Comment: I don't see any other obvious way to improve performance.  You may open a new question using my answer as the starting point.  This way, you will get more attention.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
    FROM your_table  AS src
    WHERE src.MY_SEARCH_COLUMN = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM your_table AS src2 WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE src2.MY_SEARCH_COLUMN = 123456321)
                                THEN    123456321
                                ELSE src.MY_SEARCH_COLUMN
                          END